# Max-clique problem in a non-square matrix

Tags: r, matrix, graph-theory, igraph

I have many non-square matrices like this example:

```
1    1    0
1    1    0
1    1    0
1    0    1
```

I'd like a general solution that finds the largest densely connected region in these matrices. So for my example the solution would return `rows=c(1, 2, 3), columns=c(1,2)`. That said, I'm okay with non-optimal solutions, i.e. local minima are fine.

I think this is similar to the [max-clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). However, my matrices aren't square and they don't represent graphs, so I'm having trouble using network tools for cliques like `igraph::cliques()`. How do I find densely connected regions of *non-square* matrices?

For clarification by "dense region" I mean any rectangular block in the matrix that contains all 1s, and this can be arrived at by reordering rows and columns. So ordering of rows and columns in the original matrix doesn't matter and I want to consider all permutations of orderings. I'm really looking for regions that are analogous/equivalent to cliques in an adjacency matrix, but, again, these matrices aren't square.

Comment: If you changes the order of the row or columns you will, in general, change the size of the regions.  In your example, try swapping the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Comment: What does "arrived at" mean.  Do you mean you want to look at every permutation of row and column order and consider the one that has the "largest" dense region?

Comment: I do not think that the close vote is fair, especially after OP added a clarification. It seems pretty clear that OP is looking for maximal bicliques, i.e. a submatrix of all 1s that cannot be extended by adding rows or columns to it.

Comment: The question is still very confusing.  Is it graph theory or is it not.  The question contradicts itself several times.

Comment: The beautiful thing about mathematics is that different branches connect together in unexpected ways. Many classic graph theory problems were originally phrased in terms of 0-1 matrices, without ever referring to "graph theory". It's not really productive to debate whether it is graph theory or not.

Comment: @ravenspoint I added the graph-theory tag since the solution might be graph-theory related. If the question is confusing please ask for clarification instead of closing it.

Comment: Nice history lesson.  Getting back to today, the question is a muddled mess of contradictions.

Comment: I have asked for a couple of clarification.  You are ignoring them.

Comment: @ravenspoint I added clarifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for maximal [*bicliques*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph).  igraph does not support these directly yet, but feel free to open a feature request on GitHub [here](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/new/choose). If you do, it'd be nice if you could look up and reference some algorithms to compute it.

---

For now, we can reduce this to a standard clique problem by interpreting this non-square matrix as a non-diagonal piece of a symmetric square matrix.  This is your matrix:

[image]

We transform it to this:

[image]

White represents zero, any other colour represents one. I used two non-white colours to make it clear where the original matrix appears.

The original rows 1-4 are still 1-4, the original columns 1-3 are now 5-7.

We can now look for maximal cliques which contain both "row vertices" (1-4) and "column vertices" (5-7).

---

To implement this with igraph, you can:

- Complement the matrix `m`, take `m <- 1 - m`.
- Use `graph_from_incidence_matrix(m)` to get a graph corresponding to the complement.
- Now you *could* look for independent vertex sets, see `maximal_ivs()`. But as I recall, this still uses an inefficient implementation in igraph. So I recommend taking the `complementer()` graph and looking for `max_cliques()` instead.

This what we get:

- `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, which is rows 1-4 and column 1
- `1, 2, 3, 5, 6`, which is rows 1-3 and columns 1-2 (your example solution)
- `4, 5, 7`, which is row 4 and columns 1, 3
- `5, 6, 7`, which we throw away because it contains *only* columns, and no rows.

I'll leave the detailed solution to you as I'm not much of an R programmer. I did this using IGraph/M in Mathematica.

---

First steps of an R solution, still needs filtering of results:

```r
library(igraph)

m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(1 - m)

# one way:
maximal_ivs(g)

# another way, likely faster:
max_cliques(complementer(g))

# we are basically finding cliques in:
1-as_adjacency_matrix(g)
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like exactly what I need. Although did you mean `graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m)` instead of `graph_from_incidence_matrix(m)`?

Comment: @RGregStacey No, I meant `graph_from_incidence_matrix`, which treats it as a bipartite incidence matrix, and creates separate vertices for rows and columns. This will at some point be renamed to `graph_from_biadjacency_matrix` to avoid confusion with the edge-vertex incidence matrix, but we are not there yet.

Comment: Hmm, I've edited the question to show my confusion. I'm able to get the correct answer if I manually create the square symmetric adjacency matrix as in your example and use `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`. However I'm not able to get a correct solution using `graph_from_incidence_matrix` with the complement matrix - all solutions here are two vertices only. I'm happy because the former is giving me what I want, but if you can clarify where I'm going wrong with the latter that would be instructive!

Comment: @RGregStacey I added some code at the end. Does this help? Feel free to post your own complete answer with properly written R code.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I wasn't using `complementer` correctly. That's incredibly helpful - I'm removing my code and accepting this answer.

Comment: `complementer` is really brilliant and impressive, love your `igraph`, +1!

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`igraph` approach by @szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77175383/12158757) is the most efficient and concise to address your problem.

---

Below is another old-school solution **with base R only**, which is neither efficient nor concise as using `igraph`, but you probably can find some hints there if you would like to implement without using external helping tools.

```
f <- function(m) {
    idx <- which(m == 1, TRUE)
    res <- list(list(idx = NULL, sz = 0))
    for (k in 1:nrow(idx)) {
        i1 <- idx[k, 1]
        j1 <- idx[k, 2]
        for (i2 in i1:nrow(m)) {
            for (j2 in j1:ncol(m)) {
                if (all(m[i1:i2, j1:j2, drop = FALSE] == 1)) {
                    i <- i1:i2
                    j <- j1:j2
                    l <- length(i) * length(j)
                    maxsz <- max(unlist(lapply(res, `[[`, "sz")))
                    toadd <- list(list(
                        idx = list(i = i1:i2, j = j1:j2),
                        sz = l
                    ))
                    if (l > maxsz) {
                        res <- toadd
                    }
                    if (l == maxsz) {
                        res <- c(res, toadd)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    res
}
```

where `res` contains both the index (`$idx$i` for row and `$idx$j` for column) and size (`$sz`) info of the max clique(s), if there are multiples (see the example 2 in output section).

## Output Examples

- Example 1

Given matrix `m`

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1
```

we obtain

```
> f(m)
[[1]]
[[1]]$idx
[[1]]$idx$i
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]]$idx$j
[1] 1 2


[[1]]$sz
[1] 6
```

- Example 2

Given matrix `m`

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    0    1    1    1
```

we obtain

```
> f(m)
[[1]]
[[1]]$idx
[[1]]$idx$i
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]]$idx$j
[1] 1 2


[[1]]$sz
[1] 6


[[2]]
[[2]]$idx
[[2]]$idx$i
[1] 3 4

[[2]]$idx$j
[1] 2 3 4


[[2]]$sz
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an overly simplistic approach but,

```
matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1

which(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1
[3,]   3   1
[4,]   4   1
[5,]   1   2
[6,]   2   2
[7,]   3   2
[8,]   4   3


which(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3

rle(which(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])$values
[1] 1 2 3
```

our rows?

```
matrix(which(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2],nrow = 4)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
[4,]    1    3
```

Hummmph, which row might answer for columns? I don't think this is completely phony but I'd want to apply the approach to more matrices...
Heartened by @szabolcs comment about pre-graph theory 'take for instances'

```
matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0
rle(which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)==1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])$values
[1] 1 2 3
unique(rle(which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)==1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1])$values)
[1] 2 3
```

when asked via `rle(` on arr.ind[,2] columns, we get rows, and on arr.ind[,1], rows, we get columns, which if one can accept that sort of swap, indexes where the density of 1s are, which seemed to be the question, without squaring off the matrix, are returned.

orthogonal to our first case without `rle(`, and imagining this wrapped in `unique(`, where a query on [,1] rows informs columns and [,2] informs rows

```
matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    1    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2][which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1][1:8] %in% unique(which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1][1:4])]
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1][which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2][1:8] %in% unique(which(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2][1:4])]
[1] 2 3 2 3
```

and the multiplicity of edge cases

```
matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0

abs(which(matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1] - which(matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])
[1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1

# versus same for original matrix above

abs(which(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1] - which(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2])
[1] 0 1 2 3 1 0 1 1
```

where zeros in the result says clumped and absence of zeros says scattered.

Answer (score 1):

A function that implements the solution by @Szabolcs, including the filtering:

```
fMaxSubMat <- function(m) {
  cl <- max_cliques(complementer(graph_from_incidence_matrix(1 - m)))
  n <- vapply(cl, \(x) (s <- sum(x > nrow(m)))*(length(x) - s), 0)
  lapply(
    cl[n == max(n)], \(x) {
      r <- which(x <= nrow(m))
      m[x[r], x[-r] - nrow(m)]
    }
  )
}
```

Testing:

```
(m <- matrix(c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1), 4, 3, 1, list(letters[1:4], LETTERS[1:3])))
#>   A B C
#> a 1 1 0
#> b 1 1 0
#> c 1 1 0
#> d 1 0 1
fMaxSubMat(m)
#> [[1]]
#>   A B
#> b 1 1
#> a 1 1
#> c 1 1
```