# Finding repeated bulk of elements in R vectors

Tags: r, vector, igraph

I would like to know if there is a simple way to find all the repeated vector elements (one or more) in multiple vectors (two or more).

For example, given the following character vectors:

```
France <- c("John", "Michael" , "Bob", "Oliver")
Italy <- c("Hugo", "Oliver", "Soren", "Jackson", "John")
Spain <- c("Joseph", "David", "Bob", "John", "Leo", "Michael")
Austria <- c("Oliver", "Giovanni", "Luka")
```

I would like to say that:

"John and Oliver travelled to France and Italy", and
"John, Michael and Bob travelled to France and Spain", and
"Oliver travelled to France, Italy and Austria"

I am thinking about using binary matrix to resolve it using rows as names and columns as countries then iterate all over but I think it will be computationally expensive and I am looking for an efficient way using an available method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   There seems like a fairly standard sparse matrix representation. Consider all the literature on recommender systems: a matrix of (many) customer and (even more) products.  Here you could just use row (or column, depending on how lay it out) sums.  And if you use a dense matrix (if your data has low-enough cardinality) then it is even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some help from the igraph library. For example, first let's reshape the data

```
France <- c("John", "Michael" , "Bob", "Oliver")
Italy <- c("Hugo", "Oliver", "Soren", "Jackson", "John")
Spain <- c("Joseph", "David", "Bob", "John", "Leo", "Michael")
Austria <- c("Oliver", "Giovanni", "Luka")

pairs <- stack(tibble::lst(France, Italy, Spain, Austria))
head(pairs)
#    values    ind
# 1    John France
# 2 Michael France
# 3     Bob France
# 4  Oliver France
# 5    Hugo  Italy
# 6  Oliver  Italy
```

Then let the graph help

```
library(igraph)
adjm <- pairs |>
  graph_from_data_frame(directed=FALSE) |>
  as_adjacency_matrix()

adjm[rownames(adjm) %in% pairs$values, colnames(adjm) %in% pairs$ind]
#          France Italy Spain Austria
# John          1     1     1       0
# Michael       1     0     1       0
# Bob           1     0     1       0
# Oliver        1     1     0       1
# Hugo          0     1     0       0
# Soren         0     1     0       0
# Jackson       0     1     0       0
# Joseph        0     0     1       0
# David         0     0     1       0
# Leo           0     0     1       0
# Giovanni      0     0     0       1
# Luka          0     0     0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = list(France =France, Italy = Italy, Spain = Spain, Austria = Austria)

table(stack(my_list))

          ind
values     France Italy Spain Austria
  Bob           1     0     1       0
  David         0     0     1       0
  Giovanni      0     0     0       1
  Hugo          0     1     0       0
  Jackson       0     1     0       0
  John          1     1     1       0
  Joseph        0     0     1       0
  Leo           0     0     1       0
  Luka          0     0     0       1
  Michael       1     0     1       0
  Oliver        1     1     0       1
  Soren         0     1     0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

For statements such as "John and Oliver travelled to France and Italy", you are looking for the set of [maximal bicliques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77175285/max-clique-problem-in-a-non-square-matrix/77265800#77265800).

```
library(igraph)

trips <- list(France = France, Italy = Italy, Spain = Spain, Austria = Austria)
m <- 1L - table(stack(trips))
g <- complementer(graph_from_incidence_matrix(m))
cl <- max_cliques(g)
lapply(cl[vapply(cl, \(x) (s <- sum(x > nrow(m))) > 1L && s < length(x), FALSE)], sort)
#> [[1]]
#> + 4/16 vertices, named, from ffcf6aa:
#> [1] Oliver  France  Italy   Austria
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> + 4/16 vertices, named, from ffcf6aa:
#> [1] John   Oliver France Italy 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> + 4/16 vertices, named, from ffcf6aa:
#> [1] John   France Italy  Spain 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> + 5/16 vertices, named, from ffcf6aa:
#> [1] Bob     John    Michael France  Spain
```